# How did the Power Rangers survive the train crash?

Tags: power-rangers, power-rangers-2017

In the 2017 *Power Rangers* film,

> the five teenagers (with much more attitude than they had in the original) find the power gems and then have a getaway in a van, which culminates in them trying to cross train tracks  as a train approaches. The train hits them and they all wake up back at their homes. We see later that the van was totaled by the impact.

How did they survive this? It's not because.

> they morphed into Power Ranger armor because Zordon and Alpha 5 say they haven't morphed yet. It's not because they have a Superman level of durability because during the scene where they jump across the chasm, Jason lands wrong and blood comes from his mouth (thus a much larger impact of a train ramming into them would have caused an even greater injury). And this version of Power Rangers doesn't seem to have the teleporters that the original series had, so it can't be that Zordon beamed them away. Furthermore, this is the only time that they have blackouts in the entire film.

So how is it that the five teenagers were able to survive the train crash?

Comment: A wizard did it

Comment: The novelisation is no help. It's just left unexplained.

Comment: It was just a flesh wound!  They got better.

Comment: mabye they didn't....see Lewis and "The Last Battle" ;)

Answer (score 3):

Given the historical MMPR abilities, it is likely that they were teleported away, perhaps instinctively, by the Morphing Grid or their Power Coins.  I'm not sure that this is the case though, as the historical teleportation ability was possessed by the Command Center (replaced in the movie by Zordon's ship) not a natural ability of the Rangers.

They also are not demonstrated using any form of teleportation later in the movie, even when it would make sense for them to do so.  Thus, it remains a plot hole.

It would have been nice if they thought to ask Zordon or Alpha about their escape, but they did not (in the final theatrical release).  For this reason, we can't be sure if they teleported or simply were thrown clear/escaped and made their way home on foot.  If they did escape without teleportation, they obviously recovered quickly.

Comment: This video shows that the power coins "activated", by way of flashing the individual colours (yellow, blue, pink, etc). Other than this tiny and easily missable detail, there is no other explanation for this scene

Answer (score 1):

The ship's systems presumably did the teleportation because the 5 teenagers were thought to potentially be Power Rangers. I do not think that this is a plot hole as another user suggests. Instead, the movie just reveals a layer at a time and the viewer is left to interpolate some details. If the ship can wake Zordon and Alpha and do other administrative tasks, then the ship should be able to protect and prepare potential candidates as part of the same protocols.